# Ehcache light weight package for in memory cache with TTL?

Tags: java, maven, caching, ehcache

I would like to use basic Ehcache feature (in memory cache with TTL) in my application.
Latest 2.9.0 ehcache maven dependency have a 8.7Mb size.
But in [ehcache website](http://ehcache.org/about/features) say that "Small foot print".

Which package are they using (very old version ?). Why is so big now ?

Comment: Good question! Can you detail your question a little, what would you consider a "basic feature"?

Comment: a simple in memory cache system with TTL.

Comment: Maybe you can edit the question title and generalize it?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer why EHCache is so big, but I can answer the question for a lightweight efficient and high performance in memory Java cache with TTL (aka expiry). Please take a look on [cache2k](http://cache2k.org).

Disclaimer one: I am the author for cache2k.

Disclaimer two: From release 0.19 to 0.20 the product gained size about the factor of 3, counting now 251kb (cache2k-core). The reason for this is that a lot of code is included for persistence and off heap support. At some time, I will cut this out into a separate module, since this is not always needed (e.g. on Android).

If you have further questions on cache2k, just add them to stack overflow.

If cache2k is not your thing (it is still quite evolving and needs more documentation), I think the standard pick for a lightweight cache is Google Guava. Using Guava adds a Jar with lots of stuff not needed for caching, however, most products have Guava as dependency anyway.

Comment: thanks for this option. But is it stable and robust for production use  ? (0.x says that is always in development)

Comment: It is 0.x since I might do changes in the API and does not contain all features I like to see in 1.x. All releases are robust and used in production by ourselves.

Comment: Yes, I am. I like to track what is going on, and what is the general direction in an open manner, so hence the todo list. However, that may be problematically, since you cannot see the priority of the issues. E.g. some stuff is related to storage&persistence, which is not ready to use yet, and marked as such in the release notes. Another problem is, that it is not cleaned up before any release. So what to do? Remove it, to not confuse anyone? Another question: Have you compared this to the entries, e.g. in the EHCache issue tracker? Anyway, thanks for the comment!

Comment: I think it is a good idea to work more with the github issue tracker, so people can comment on this. Notes on stuff that is yet unfinished I better keep internal.

Comment: I think cache2k is a good alternative but I cannot add it directly in my critical business application without testing it before... but I keep a steady eye on this project. Thanks for your quick replies.

Comment: If you step on some bugs or need a specific feature, I'd happy for feedback. If you do test some specific scenario, why not put that on github? BTW: In my FOSDEM talk last sunday, you can find some latest performance figures: http://www.slideshare.net/cruftex/cache2k-java-caching-turbo-charged-fosdem-2015

Comment: Ah, I forgot, right now documentation is quite lagging behind. If you need to know, how to solve any specific issue with cache2k, just ask it on SO or add an issue. This way I can spend time on working on stuff that is actually need, and not that I think people might be missing....

Answer (score 1):

The website makes the claim for version `2.2.3` and that remains true.
But indeed the Ehcache jar has grown in size over time and it looks like the website has not been updated with that information.

Version 2.7.0 was released as a single jar including its internal dependencies rather than having `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache` simply be a pom pulling in dependencies.

One reason for the growth are the added monitoring features, which can be accessed through ReST calls. Unfortunately, that is also a point where documentation is lacking.

If you are interested in the topic, have a look at the following:

- `net.sf.ehcache.config.ManagementRESTServiceConfiguration` for enabling/configuring the ReST services,
- The package `net.sf.ehcache.management.resource.services` module in `management-ehcache-v2` of Ehcache code.

In parallel, work started in [Ehcache 3](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3) plans to restore a "small footprint" option.